# RSVP.hash - promise Not works like returning a object without promise

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, rsvp-promise

In my model I am retuning a data without a `promise` like :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id ); //works
  }
});
```

It works fine. But when I add the `RSVP` promise, I am not getting the data to my models.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        model: this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id ) //not working
    })
  }
});
```

What is the issue to add a `promise` here?
Or what is the correct way to resove the promise here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to access it using `model.model.propName` in hbs

Comment: @kumkanillam - what is the correct way to prevent the data on refresh in ember page

Comment: works fine. very thanks.

Comment: There is nothing specific to refresh, your model hook should return the data every time..this is not specific question if you got ember-twiddle it will be easy to fix

Comment: I see there is a question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559727/how-to-keep-the-data-on-refresh-a-page

Comment: Why would you want to use RSVP in this instance? - and why would you push a key of model into 'model' ?

Comment: @kumkanillam - `model.model.propName` would work, but shouldn't the OP use a different key??  `model.student.name` etc?

Comment: Yes you are right @sheriffderek there is no need to RSVP.hash here and I don't know the `card-list` property names. So I tried to convey OP to use property name available in model