# How to keep the data on refresh a page?

Tags: ember.js

I am getting my data from the model. after the model integrated to page, when I refresh the page the data goes away.

I would like to prevent the data still on refresh. what is the correct way to do this in `EmberJs` any one show me the correct way to prevent my `data` from refresh?

my model code :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id ); //works
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params) {

        if(this.store.hasRecordForId('card-list', params.id)){
            return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                model: this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id ) 
            })
        }
    //I am trying for refresh. but throws error as
//Error while processing route: cs2i.balance.balanceEdit Ember Data Request GET /api/card-lists/4196074912005007 returned a 404
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            model: this.store.findRecord('card-list', params.id ) 
        })
      }
    });
```

Comment: RSVP.hash adds records to the model... so - having a key of 'model' seems like a bad idea.

Comment: ok, will change that. But what would be the correct way to get data on refresh from child route

Comment: In the child .... you would need a parameter - often from the url - to fill the dynamic segment - and then findRecord with it's ID or slug etc. - but if you are only grabbing one thing... you shouldn't use the RSVP here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for existing record unless fetching that.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    if(this.store.hasRecordForId('card-list', params.id))
      return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id );
    return this.store.findRecord('card-list', params.id );
  }
});
```

Comment: Not working, getting error. please see my update in question

Comment: //I am trying for refresh. but throws error as
//Error while processing route: cs2i.balance.balanceEdit Ember Data Request GET /api/card-lists/4196074912005007 returned a 404

Answer (score 1):

You must be 'peeking' the record of a parent route that fetches the record with query or findRecord or findAll etc... so - there could be many reasons your data is 'goes away'...

If you are *not* in a child route of something... that peekRecord has nothing to 'peek'... so, you'd have to check for the record... or get the modelFor('model-name') - from a parent route... - so, you'll need to provide more information about the context of your code.

```
// imports whatevers...
model(parameters) {
  return this.store.findRecord('thing', parameter.id);
}
```

or....

```
model() {
  var x = this.modelFor('parentModel');
  // do something with x... query... find etc...
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the data from child route only. as like Ebrahim suggesion I tried by getting error. updated in question

Comment: it's important that we agree that the application route is entered... then the parent... then the child - so, the models are being added to the overall context... but how the child knows what's it's dynamic segment is - is usually the issue.